# Android camerax stop working after some pictures taken

Tags: android, performance

I have had some problems with android camerax v1.0.0-Beta4

It looks like memory problems or something related (maybe), the user took many pictures without problems, but after that the app doesn´t show the preview anymore and sometimes crashes.

The devices in witch  the problem was detedted:

- samsung SM-S337TL
- huawei y9 prime
- HUAWEI JKM-LX3
- SM-J710MN API:27

The code was taken from https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

Log error from SM_J7

```
[ImageReader-1920x1080f23m4-6188-27] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
06-08 16:16:30.317 E/BufferItemConsumer( 6188): [ImageReader-1920x1080f23m4-6188-27] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
06-08 16:16:31.651 W/FirebaseRemoteConfig( 6188): No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
06-08 16:16:31.651 W/FirebaseRemoteConfig( 6188): No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_feature_enabled'.
06-08 16:16:32.252 W/CameraDevice-JV-0( 6188): CameraDevice 0 died unexpectedly
06-08 16:16:32.258 E/Camera2CameraImpl( 6188): Error observed on open (or opening) camera device 0: ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188): Session 9: Exception while stopping repeating: 
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188): android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2219)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1003)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:394)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.closeCameraCaptureSession(CaptureSession.java:572)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CaptureSession.release(CaptureSession.java:520)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.releaseSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:493)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.resetCaptureSession(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1045)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.closeCamera(Camera2CameraImpl.java:410)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.handleErrorOnOpen(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1445)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl$StateCallback.onError(Camera2CameraImpl.java:1412)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onError(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:119)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.compat.CameraDeviceCompat$StateCallbackExecutorWrapper$3.run(CameraDeviceCompat.java:177)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:110)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:230)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:172)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
06-08 16:16:32.270 E/CameraCaptureSession( 6188):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
06-08 16:16:33.257 E/CameraManagerGlobal( 6188): Camera service is unavailable
06-08 16:16:34.263 E/CameraManagerGlobal( 6188): Camera service is unavailable
06-08 16:16:35.269 E/CameraManagerGlobal( 6188): Camera service is unavailable
06-08 16:16:36.275 E/CameraManagerGlobal( 6188): Camera service is unavailable
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188): Photo capture failed: Camera is closed.
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188): androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Camera is closed.
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest.lambda$notifyCallbackError$1$ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest(ImageCapture.java:1992)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$ImageCapture$ImageCaptureRequest$1G7WSvt8TANxhZtOyewefm68pg4.run(Unknown Source:8)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188): Caused by: androidx.camera.core.CameraClosedException: Camera is closed.
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.abortImageCaptureRequests(ImageCapture.java:712)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.onStateDetached(ImageCapture.java:708)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2CameraImpl.lambda$notifyStateDetachedToUseCases$12(Camera2CameraImpl.java:700)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.-$$Lambda$Camera2CameraImpl$w4MCdDIzOHUZjADo0Cs_j5Ij7CA.run(Unknown Source:2)
06-08 16:16:41.583 E/CameraFragment( 6188):     ... 7 more
06-08 16:16:48.425 W/FirebaseRemoteConfig( 6188): No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'sessions_max_length_minutes'.
```

I hope you can help me, regards!!!